# Un drôle de choix de + infinitif

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

Axel pose une question à Jean qui n'a pas une bonne réputation. May pense :

> Un drôle de choix **de** poser cette question à Jean. (*)

Sur Internet, je trouve beaucoup d'exemples contenant *un drôle de choix **de** + nom*, mais j'ai trouvé un seul exemple avec  *un drôle de choix **de** + infinitif*.

Pourriez-vous me dire si ma phrase (*) est correcte ?

Comment: Toujours des questions subtiles que les vôtres…

Comment: @LPH Parce que sinon je connais la réponse moi-même :)

Answer (score 5):

> Poser cette question à Jean ((c')est) un drôle de choix.

Avec un attribut (ici *un drôle de choix*), on peut avoir le sujet (*poser cette question à Jean*) à la fin et quand le sujet est un infinitif (*poser...*), il est introduit par *de*, *que de* (littéraire), ou *que* (imitation des classiques) (Le bon usage, Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup>, éd. Duculot, §911b, incluant les exemples suivants) :

> C'est beau **d**'être la puce d'un lion (Hugo) 
>  Ce n'est pas
> grand'chose **que d**'aimer un être (Camus)
>  Est-ce diminuer une
> chose **qu**'en montrer les difficultés ? (Tharaud)

La phrase est correcte à mon avis.

Answer (score 2):

Il y aurait peut-être une tendance moderne à continuer à utiliser « de » lorsque le groupe nominal comprend une modification.

- le choix de fumer avant le déjeuner/le choix de ne pas voter/le choix d'écrire de gauche à droite/le choix de parler lentement/… (*pas de problème lorsqu'il n'y a pas de modification*)

Dès que l'on utilise une modification on crée une incertitude.

- la médiocre décision de faire le partage

On ne comprend pas très bien si « médiocre » modifie « décision », c'est à dire si faire le partage n'a rien de médiocre mais que la décision, de la façon dont elle a été prise est médiocre, ou, si au contraire, c'est la décision de faire le partage qui est médiocre, et alors dans ce cas l'idée d'un partage est elle-même médiocre. Pour éviter de susciter à l'esprit cette logique ambigüe la pratique souvent relevée dans la langue soutenue consiste à utiliser les locutions « que celui de » (masculin), « que celle de » (féminin), etc.

Apparemment cela n'est pas traité dans LBU, mais on y trouve l'exemple suivant.

> LBU § 405 **a)** Grand délice QUE celui de noyer son regard dans l'immensité du ciel et de la mer ! (BAUDEL., Pet. poèmes en pr., Confiteor de l'artiste.)

Donc, dans une langue plus châtiée on écrirait cette forme comme ci-dessous.

- Drôle de choix que celui de poser cette question à Jean !

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie modification par un adjectif ; le texte de la question est une quasi-exclamation ; « langue châtié » est du vocabulaire bien connu qui correspond à langage soutenu ; « broder », c'est autre chose, revoyez vos définitions. « Le choix de fumer » ou  « le choix d'hululer avec les chouettes la nuit », qu'importe ? Ce sont des exemples qui insistent sur la parfaite correction de la forme lorsqu'il n'y a pas d'adjectif (ça encore, c'est évident).

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Donc on ne dirait pas « Drôle de choix _que celui de_ poser cette question à Jean ! » ? Ni « Grand délice QUE celui de noyer son regard » ?

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Ça dit bien la même chose mais  exprimée avec « de » il y a quelque chose qui n'est pas « bien », et la preuve c'est que les écrivains dans le passé ont ajouté, et cela de façon assez consistante, les mots « que celui », « que celle », etc. Pourquoi auraient-ils compliqué ainsi cette construction si ce n'avait été pour l'améliorer ? Personnellement je trouve que l'effet incertain que la lecture produit  sur moi-même est dû à cette impression d'ambigüité.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Si LBU avait toutes les réponses croyez-vous que l'on parlerait de grammaire sur le présent site ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119001/discussion-between-thelee-lavoie-and-lph).